# Websphere Node Federating issue

Tags: websphere

I have created a DMGR profile in my host which is successs. On the same host i have  created a managed node.  Now when i am trying to federate the node to DMGR i am getting below error :

**ADMU006E : Exception creating Deployment Manager Connection: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host **** at port 8879**

Now to verify SOAP connection i have run the below command :

**    wsadmin.sh -conntype SOAP -port -host   **

Running this script from bin in dmgr profile.. it is connecting fine but failing with the same exception when running from bin directory of managed node profile.

To verify further i done the same setup in a different host by creating a dmgr and a node. It was all fine. DMGR profile created and node got federated in one go.

Not sure what exactly is the issue here.

Have verified that my port and hoat details are all correct. Also that my dmgr is running.

Comment: Hi manish,
so you mean that DMGR SOAP port is 8879 (you can check it in profiles/myDmgr/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt or using admin console - System Administration / Deployment manager / ports). Now the wsadmin command must contain -host somehost -port soapPort otherwise it uses defaults from properties/wsadmin.properties.

Comment: Hi Michal, i have verified that my SOAP Port detail is 8879. I can see the same in wsadmin.properties, serverIndex.xml as well as in SystemOut.log when dmgr is restarted.

Comment: That's strange, then you can enable wsadmin trace (I think in wsadmin properties in dmgrprofile/properties/ and try to run dmgrprofile/bin/wsadmin.sh -conntype SOAP -host yourhost -port 8879 and inspect the wasadmin trace log. If it is a TCP/IP connection issue, there would be connection timeout, if SSL/TLS then most probably connection reset, if another problem, please share the trace

Comment: Hi Michal,
wsadmin.sh -connType SOAP -host yourhost - port 8879 is working from DMGR bin directory, but unable to do the same from managed node profile bin directory.

Comment: but to federate a node, you need to do the following:
<new_profile_to_be_federated>/bin/addNode.sh <dmgr_hostName> <dmgr_soap_port>

Comment: Yes Michal.. i have run the addNode command to federate the node to dmgr.. i am getting the same exception that it is unable to connect to SOAP connector port of Dmgr.. i.e 8879..  i have done a complete new setup on a different host and i am able to federate the node to dmgr.. now i am thinking that it is some issue at Host level or can be that something is corrupted of the WAS installation on the system but i am unable to get hold of the exact issue here... :(

Comment: Hi Michal, As adviced i have increased the trace for wsadmin and tried to test SOAP connector test and in trace log could find below error :  java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN= , OU=, ... is not trusted; internal cause is : java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error.   I am not able to understand as we have only created a dmgr profile and a node profile and trying to federate. No changes are done to any certificates. Is it that something related to WAS is corrupted. ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Michal, ephonk for your inputs. 
Found the solution to above issue.

Issue was with the java.security file present in the *WAS_HOME/java/jre/lib/security* location.

In this file the SSL values were as below : 
***ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl***

We changed to below values and were successfully able to Federate the node to DMGR.

***ssl.SocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLServerSocketFactory***

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be relevant, but I've seen this when the SOAP port isn't open in the firewall.  Are you sure traffic on that port is allowed?

Comment: Hi Ephonk, How do i check if my SOAP port is open in the firewall or to verify if traffic on that port is allowed. My only confusion here is when i try to connect to SOAP port using wsadmin.sh script i am able to connect from dmgr profile but not from a managed node profile.

Comment: well...  that's probably not your problem then.  You wouldn't be able to connect one way and then not the other.  Sorry, wish i could be more help.